# g.Raphael 0.51 error in IE

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, graphael

I'm trying to do generate a sample pie chart from raphael.min.js version 2.1.2

I'm using

```
raphael.min.js
```

and

```
 g.raphael.min.js
```

in my code.

```
ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined in corresponding to the line of code :-

--> Raphael.el.popup = function (d, a, b, f) {
```

Please help.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Is the code that you have posted the code that triggers the error or just the error message that is shown? If it is just the error message can you add the code that causes the error.

Comment: the error message that is shown